# How to init vue3 project with webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs3

I found below command to init vue JS project with webpack

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init webpack my-project
```

But the problem is its initialize using Vue 2 and webpack 3.

anyone know similar way to scaffold vue 3 project with latest webpack 5.

Answer (score 1):

Only official scaffolding available for Vue3 is [create-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue) . It uses Vite instead of webpack though. It is recommended way (see note on top https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html )

If you want to use Webpack anyway - I guess you would need to init webpack project and install Vue as a package.